Angular 19: blank line in imports section
Ever since I've updated my Angular project to version 19 (latest), I get this weird blank line in the imports section of every component.
For example:
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
...
[this line here]
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";
...

I can't pin-point what triggers it to be like that, but it's definitely something that keeps coming back, perhaps after save or format or something else.
I can't think of a good reason for this to happen, and eventually it doesn't affect my work or the way the app runs and builds, but anyway how do I stop this behavior?

could you replicate in stackblitz maybe it has something to do with your prettier or eslint configuration

Did you update your eslint version or something like this ?
